# Real-time Filesystem Replication between 2 NAS and ubuntu 12.04.3

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, network-attached-storage, file-replication-services

I have two 16TB NAS setup and are mounted on one server. What is the best way to implement real-time file replication of write to 1 NAS to the second NAS.

I can mount the 2 NAS in one server but I'm not sure what tool to use.

Thanks.

Comment: I am looking at GlusterFS but can I do the replication on one machine only since I am handling two NAS.

Comment: rsync could work fairly well

Comment: Can you give more detail about what you're doing and why you need to do it this way?

Comment: "real time" means very different things to different use cases. Are you looking for synchronous writes? The quick and dirty is to use Rsync like Sverre mentioned but there can be a lot of complications depending on what your end goal is.

Comment: End goal is for both of my NAS to have the same content. If I create a file or update a file in one NAS, all of those changes must be replicated/writtent to the other NAS with minimal latency. I've used rsync but it needs to be invoked via cron.

Comment: Anyone have nay idea how can I do this? Thanks!